# Connect performSegue w/ prepareForSegue in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Sorry for the vague title, I've never been really good with words but this is the general outline of what I want to do.

I have two view controllers,
-One called settings
-One called setDate

In the settings view controller I have two buttons, one called 'summary time', the other called 'daily time'

Each are linked to different IBActions that segue to the setDate view controller using performSegue.

My question is how could I perform an if statement in the setDate view controller by comparing the sender that performed the segue?

Sorry if I don't make much sense but could anyone help me?

Comment: did you check sourceViewController?

Comment: You can get the source and destination view controllers from the segue object. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Not really, both the buttons are in the same view controller, I need to find out which button performed the segue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You normally configure the 'setDate' view controller in the 'prepareForSegue' method of the 'settings' view controller.  Something like this:

```
class SettingsViewController : ... {
  // ...

  override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "segueSummaryTime" {
      let dest = segue.destinationViewController as SetDateViewController
      // configure dest for 'summary time'
      // for example:
      dest.isForSummary = true
      // ...
    }
    else if segue.identifier == "segueDetailTime" {
      // as above but for 'detail time'
    }
  }

  // ..
}
```

For the above, you should have linked each button to a different segue, each with an identifier as I've illustrated above.